# android inAppPurchases using anjlab?

Tags: java, android

I am working on android anjlab in app purchasing.
Code was working fine.But suddenly what happend , I dont know app is crashing when we try to subscribe.
I dont know what is the problem.I am thinking there is problem with key.But i dont know how we check key is valid or not.
I am following these tutorials.

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/README.md.

Crashing is in this code..

```
@Subscribe
public void onRequestPurchaseEvent (RequestPurchaseEvent event)
{

    final SkuDetails listingDetails;
    if(event.purchaseID.equals(BaseConstants.YEARLY_SUBSCRIPTION))
    listingDetails=bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(BaseConstants.YEARLY_SUBSCRIPTION);
    else
        listingDetails=bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(BaseConstants.SINGE_ISSUE);

    LoggerDebug.d("aaa","event: "+event.purchaseID);
    LoggerDebug.d("bbb","Billing Price: "+"560Rs");
          PurchaseDialogFragment.createInstance(this,event.purchaseID,listingDetails.priceText).show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);

}
```